# Почему не банится отвеченный на сообщение пользователь?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет любителям программирования! Сразу говорю о своей проблеме. Помогите пожалуйста, что делать, если я пытаюсь забанить пользователя, который получил ответ от другого пользователя.
Я использую библиотеку aiogram для написании кода своего телеграмм бота. Я написал отдельный хендлер, который написан для команды 'cut_with_a_grinder'. Суть команды такова - когда пользователь отвечает на сообщение другого пользователя этой командой, ТОТ ДРУГОЙ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ БАНИЛСЯ НА 1 МИНУТУ В ЧАТЕ!!! Мой код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='cut_with_a_grinder')
async def go(message: types.Message):
    t = 60
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    try:
        user_id = message.reply_to_message.from_user.id
    except AttributeError:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
    if 'count' not in await dp.storage.get_data(user=user_id):
        # Если информации нет, создаем ее
        await dp.storage.update_data(user=user_id, count=1, timestamp=time())
    else:
        data = await dp.storage.get_data(user=user_id)
        count = data['count'] + 1
        await dp.storage.update_data(user=user_id, count=count, timestamp=time())
        if count >= 1:
            if time() - data['timestamp'] < t:
                await message.answer(f"<i>{message.from_user.first_name} разрезал {user_id} болгаркой ️, и {user_id} того - гг вп ☠️⚰️ </i>\n"
                                     f"<b> {user_id} не может писать в течении минуты из-за того, что {message.from_user.first_name} разрезал его(е) болгаркой ️. Поступок сигмы ‍♂️ </b>\n", parse_mode='html')
                await message.answer_sticker("CAACAgIAAx0Cct53MQACCJhlTpF5pWt1FXZsn-vVoIHx0mvolQACfwADkTmcHFyP-rpj7WlqMwQ")
                await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time() + 61)
                await message.answer("<b>Домой</b>", parse_mode='html')
```

```
Почему ошибка возникает именно в restrict_chat_member ? Буду вам благодарен, если поможете)
```

Гайды в интернете искал, их попросту нету, из всех, что я смотрел(

Comment: Приложите текст ошибки в вопрос